# Удаление меток в яндекс картах

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Есть функция, которая выполняется каждые 5 сек, в результате чего выводятся метки на карте:

```
var myPlacemark = [];
function(data) {
    console.log(data); 
    var a = data;
    
    for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {   
        var ch = a[i].ch, poz=a[i].poz, la = a[i].la, lo =a[i].lo;
        var img = "/../../../images/poz.php?ch="+ch+"&poz="+poz+"&rnd="+poz;
        console.log(img);
        ymaps.option.presetStorage.add("my#customIcon"+ch+poz, {
                            iconImageHref: img,
                            iconImageOffset: [-12, -12],
                            iconImageSize: [34, 34]  
        }); 
        myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark( [la, lo],{iconContent:"" }, {preset: "my#customIcon"+ch+poz}, {draggable: true});                         
        myCollection.add(myPlacemark); 
        obj1=myPlacemark;
    }
}
myMap.geoObjects.add(myCollection);
```

Я хотел бы вызвать новый метод чтобы перерисовать метки `myMap.container.fitToViewport()` но при этом удалить старые метки методом `MyCollection.removeAll()`, подскажите как это реализовать?

Comment: Не ужели никто не в курсе?

Answer (score 2):

Метки надо занести в глобальную переменную, допустим `var CasheData`. Далее перед прорисовкой гео объектов необходимо сравнить CasheData c результатом `ajax` запроса , если метки не изменили положение то не прорисовывать их, если да то вывести их на карту.

Ответ содержится в [этом посту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/266882/javascript-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82).