# Проверить объект

Tags: ajax, javascript

Подскажите метод как поместить сформированный объект при AJAX запросе, который формируеться каждые 5сек,  и поместить его в другой объект,чтобы при следуеющем запросе можно было сверить на различе элементов внутри объекта?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно просто создать переменную на уровень выше. В нее будет записываться объект и с ним будет сравниваться результат, который возвращает AJAX:

```
var cacheData;
$.post('blah-blah.php', {test: 'test'}, function(data){
    if (cacheData === data) {}; // Сравниваем
    cacheData = data; // Перезаписываем объект
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, а подскажите .diff - это метод сравнения? где про него можно почитать?

Comment: Нет, это просто условное свойство, которое я сравнивал для примера. Оно ничего не значит

Comment: Записывается строка, а не объект. В связи с этим сравнение элементов невозможно. Так то @MrFranke правильно начал ответ. Сначала лучше ничего никуда не переводить и сравнивать то, что есть. Допустим, если пришла строка, отличная от предыдущей, то парсим строку в объект с помощью json.parse.

Comment: var cacheInString = '';
 var cacheInObject = {};

 function callbackFunc (data) {
  if(data !== cacheInString) {
   var parseData = JSON.parse(data)
   , diff = {};

   for(var key in parseData) {
    if(cacheInObject[key] == undefined || acheInObject[key] != parseData[key]) {
     diff[key] = {
      'last': cacheInObject[key],
      'new': parseData[key]
     };
    }
   }
   console.log(diff);
   
   cacheInString = data;
   cacheInObject = parseData;
   return;
  }
  console.log('нет элементов для сравнения');
 }